# How to disable / enable button when in CKEditor when source function is on?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

When using the source function in CKEditor, some buttons (usually those related to style) are disabled while some button are still available (usually those not related to style) The following is a screenshot of the [official demo](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/18-03-19-07-05/standard/samples/) showing what is disabled and what is not.

[image]

I am writing a few custom plugin following the [official guide](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1.html) with some twist of my own. Some of them, like adding abbreviation in the official guide, should be enabled even in source mode, while some other related to style should be disabled. The problem is, where should I set such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use`modes` property.

```
editor.addCommand('foo', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('fooDialog'));
editor.commands.foo.modes = { wysiwyg: 1, source: 1 };
```

or

```
editor.addCommand('foo', {
    modes: { wysiwyg: 1, source: 1 },
    //...
});
```

More info:

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_command.html#property-modes
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_commandDefinition.html#property-modes

Comment: While this does the trick to enable / disable the command, but the button itself is not changing to grey when setting `source:0`..... do you know how to set it? Or should I ask a new question if this needs a lot of testing?

Uploaded. Wait for your response before marking as correct answer.

Comment: The button is automatically disabled in Source mode when setting `source: 0` because it is linked to the command. The opposite happens when `source: 1`. Perhaps you need to clear browser cache to reload plugin. Otherwise, please show some sample code of your plugin (`addCommand`, `modes` and `addButton` code).

Comment: I mean, the button is disabled correctly (at least, not action on click), but the button is not turned into grey.......

Comment: Wait, the button is still clickable? Did you clear the browser cache?

Comment: No, the button is not clickable, but the button remains in the original color. (The hover border is gone though)

Comment: That's weird. Does the Abbreviation plugin work as intended?

Comment: Yes, on function, it works as intended. Those enabled function works, and those disabled function stop working under source mode. The only problem is styling. That's why I give upvoted as it really works.

Comment: If you want, edit your post to show some sample code including `addCommand`, `modes` and `addButton` code.

Comment: The problem is now solved by using CSS brutally. I still have the question but I think I better open a new question for that if it needs to have sample code added..